# How we can pass <strong> in template literal

Tags: reactjs

`${notificationData && notificationData.length} other open problems with this asset` in this, i want the text should be bold for 'open problems'. Can we do

Ex: `${notificationData && notificationData.length} other <strong>open problems</strong> with this asset`

Answer (score 0):

Use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: ${notificationData && notificationData.length} other <strong>open problems</strong> with this asset` }} />
```

Comment: `${notificationData && notificationData.length} other <strong>open problems</strong> with this asset`. the entire string is in template literal (` `)

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) Error: `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML` must be in the form `{__html: ...}`. 

get an error. can please help.

Comment: added like below
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ _html: `${notificationData && notificationData.length} other <strong>open problems</strong> with this asset` }} />.

then getting this 
Uncaught (in promise) Error: props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML must be in the form {__html: ...}. get an error.

Comment: don't use props just dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Comment: I'm not passing any props.

Comment: You are not using template literal from what I can see in your comment

Comment: `${notificationData && notificationData.length} other <strong>open problems</strong> with this asset`.

i'm using the template literal strings (` `), they are missing, when i post this comment.

Comment: Check out the updated answer suman. I forgot about __html. I have included it now